# Determine what kind of stationary point you have in $(0,0)$ where $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2+1)^2 - 2(x^2+y^2) +4\cos(xy)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Given the function
>
> $$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2+1)^2 - 2(x^2+y^2) +4\cos(xy)$$

I know that  the taylor polynomial of degree $4$ of $f$ is equal to $5+x^4+y^4$. And I know that $x^4+y^4 \geq \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}$. Now I need to determine what kind of stationary point you have in $(0,0)$. Any hints ?

Comment: Since you have the Taylor polynomial centered on the origin, what happens if you vary $x$ or $y$ slightly?  Does the function increase or decrease for _both_ variables (local extremum) or increase for one, but decrease for the other (saddle point)?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner But the taylor is not exactly the same function right ?

Comment: No, that's true, but a Taylor series is an approximation to the function at a particular point, in this case, (0,0).  (If you expand out the polynomials and use $\cos(xy)$ up to the $x^2y^2$ term, after cancellation you only retain the terms you've indicated out to fourth-degree.)  So $5 + x^4 + y^4$ _is_ a very good description of the behavior of $f(x,y)$ in the neighborhood of the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the Taylor series you can rewrite it such as
$$\hat f(0,0)=5+(\Delta x)^4+(\Delta y)^4+O^5$$
It is clear that any variation in $x$ or $y$ increases the value of $\hat f$ and therefore $(0,0)$ is a minimum.

Comment: I think I understand this. But than I don't understand why I needed to calculate: $x^4+y^4 \geq \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}$

Comment: Why do you think that you have to calculate it? Is it in your textbook?

Comment: I need to show 3 things: a) the taylor polynomial of degree 4 of $f$ is equal to $5+x^4 +y^4$ b) $x^4+y^4 \geq \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}$ c) determine what kind of stationary point you have in $(0,0)$. I would have thought I need $a)$ AND $b) for $c)$, but it sems like I only need $a)$. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: In my opinion you only need a)... I don't see any reason why you may need b). I guess in b) you need to find Taylor for LHS and RHS and compare both Taylor's.